# SQL Server 2008 Express backup and restore to test

Tags: sql-server

We have a database system currently in SQL Server 2008 Express that we want to copy to a SQL Server 2012 server for testing. Having never moved a SQL Server database I have a few questions.

1. Can I take a full backup without taking the database offline?
2. Our database is 6Gb, however our `.LDF` file is over 200Gb. Can I take just a backup of the data and not bring over the transaction log?
3. Is the right click Backup in SSMS better/worse than doing `BACKUP DATABASE` in T-SQL?

Just making sure I have my ducks in a row since I don't have a current test DB with any real data to test the process. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Full Backup always constitutes of (.mdf) and (.ldf) files as a whole DB inside Backup.If 200GB (.ldf) is the problem, then as Raz Said, Switching the recovery model to 'SIMPLE'. Follow this; Take full backup if possible before switching [if free disk space is present].
Change the recovery model to 'SIMPLE' and click OK. then again revert to 'FULL' model. Shrink the (.LDF) file now it should be able to see the (.LDF) size reduced to few MBs. Now take Full Backup and move it to 2012 server.

Answer (score 0):

You can certainly backup the database without taking it offline.

Your database will probably be around ~6GB in actual size.  You most likely have the database in FULL recovery mode and have never taken a Log backup.  That's a different discussion but will hopefully be resolved when you move the database.

Backing up through the GUI or TSQL is the same.  In fact the GUI should have a button at the top saying "script" which will allow you to see the commands that will be generated.

Comment: Thank you. I wasn't sure if the backup actually took the LDF with it or not and I was concerned about locking tables while people were doing things.

Comment: Also I agree the log file needs to be addressed and will be on the new server. I just inherited these SQL servers (Oracle previously) so in the learning curve still.

Comment: Ok so I tested with another much smaller database. MDF was 1Gb, Log 2Gb. It seems to be taking the LDF with the MDF once you restore the database to another server. Is there a way to do this without taking the LDF content with it?

Comment: The LDF has to copy portions needed to do log re-do operations (or roll fwd/roll backwards) in order to stay transitionally consistent.  You should absolutely take care of your log file *immediately*.  If you don't need 'point in time recovery' and are OK with just full/diff backups, please change the DB to 'SIMPLE' recovery mode, checkpoint, then shrink and expand to maintain your VLF count under 100

Comment: Part of the transition to the new server is to take care of the log file. Taking the full backup and then shrinking the log file on the new server. Apparently no one was doing any backups on the server which is why the log file is so huge.